# How to change an image when a moveable element touches it?

Tags: javascript, html, image, drag-and-drop

I want to create a function so that when an `object(img1)` is on `img2a` it will make it turn into `img2b`. I have to pieces of code that do the 2 things separately by I can't seem to combine them.

I found the code for changing the image (bellow)

```html
<img id="myImg" src="image1.jpg">
<button id="myButton">Change Image</button>
```

```js
// JavaScript code
const myImg = document.getElementById("myImg");
const myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");

myButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  myImg.src = "image2.jpg";
});
```

and I have the code to move the object (bellow)

```js
     <img src="https://en.js.cx/clipart/soccer-gate.svg" id="gate" class="droppable">
   
     <img src="https://en.js.cx/clipart/ball.svg" id="ball">
   
     <script>
       let currentDroppable = null;
   
       ball.onmousedown = function(event) {
   
         let shiftX = event.clientX - ball.getBoundingClientRect().left;
         let shiftY = event.clientY - ball.getBoundingClientRect().top;
   
         ball.style.position = 'absolute';
         ball.style.zIndex = 1000;
         document.body.append(ball);
   
         moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);
   
         function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
           ball.style.left = pageX - shiftX + 'px';
           ball.style.top = pageY - shiftY + 'px';
         }
   
         function onMouseMove(event) {
           moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);
   
           ball.hidden = true;
           let elemBelow = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
           ball.hidden = false;
   
           if (!elemBelow) return;
   
           let droppableBelow = elemBelow.closest('.droppable');
           if (currentDroppable != droppableBelow) {
             if (currentDroppable) { // null when we were not over a droppable before this event
               leaveDroppable(currentDroppable);
             }
             currentDroppable = droppableBelow;
             if (currentDroppable) { // null if we're not coming over a droppable now
               // (maybe just left the droppable)
               enterDroppable(currentDroppable);
             }
           }
         }
   
         document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
   
         ball.onmouseup = function() {
           document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
           ball.onmouseup = null;
         };
   
       };
   
       function enterDroppable(elem) {
         elem.style.background = 'pink';
       }
   
       function leaveDroppable(elem) {
         elem.style.background = '';
       }
   
       ball.ondragstart = function() {
         return false;
       };
     </script>
   
   
   </body>
   </html>
```

I would appreciate any and all help I could get.
Specifically what I am looking for is help with the attribute used as instead of a color change I want an image change I've tried a couple of thing like `img` but it hasn't worked yet.

Comment: JavaScript is not Java.  They are completely different things.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to it I just looked it up and your right sorry again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, I changed your code and you can see the result in the sample code which I've provided for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="https://en.js.cx/clipart/soccer-gate.svg" style="width: 100px;" id="gate" class="droppable">

    <img src="https://en.js.cx/clipart/ball.svg" id="ball">

    <script>
        let currentDroppable = null;
        let gateAddr = "https://en.js.cx/clipart/soccer-gate.svg";

        ball.onmousedown = function(event) {

            let shiftX = event.clientX - ball.getBoundingClientRect().left;
            let shiftY = event.clientY - ball.getBoundingClientRect().top;

            ball.style.position = 'absolute';
            ball.style.zIndex = 1000;
            document.body.append(ball);

            moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

            function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
                ball.style.left = pageX - shiftX + 'px';
                ball.style.top = pageY - shiftY + 'px';
            }

            function onMouseMove(event) {
                moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

                ball.hidden = true;
                let elemBelow = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
                ball.hidden = false;

                if (!elemBelow) return;

                let droppableBelow = elemBelow.closest('.droppable');
                if (currentDroppable != droppableBelow) {
                    if (currentDroppable) { // null when we were not over a droppable before this event
                        leaveDroppable(currentDroppable);
                    }
                    currentDroppable = droppableBelow;
                    if (currentDroppable) { // null if we're not coming over a droppable now
                        // (maybe just left the droppable)
                        enterDroppable(currentDroppable);
                    }
                }
            }

            document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

            ball.onmouseup = function() {
                document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
                ball.onmouseup = null;
            };

        };

        function enterDroppable(elem) {
            elem.src = "https://www.svgrepo.com/download/116991/goal-label.svg";
        }

        function leaveDroppable(elem) {
            elem.src = gateAddr;
        }

        ball.ondragstart = function() {
            return false;
        };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Good Luck!